# not able to click on button where xpath is showing correct as per selenium IDE 2.9.1

Tags: firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to write xpath for 'New' button.

have tried:-

```
By.xpath("//form[@action='/intruvert/action/CustomRolesAction']/div/div[3]/div/a[1]")

By.xpath("//form[@name='CustomRolesForm']/div/div[3]/div/a[@style='background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);' and @title='New']")

By.xpath("//form[@name='CustomRolesForm']/div/div[3]/div/a[@title='New']")
```

but not able to click on New button.

I am not sure here if i missing anything.

kindly suggest.

here is the code:-

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div class="bodywrap">
<form action="/intruvert/action/CustomRolesAction" method="post" name="CustomRolesForm">
<input type="hidden" value="CustomRolesDetails_t" name="userAction"/>
<input type="hidden" value="fullaccess" name="accessRight"/>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="uuid"/>
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="fromTab"/>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="selectedDomain"/>
<input type="hidden" value="/My Company:0/Manager:0" name="resourceName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="MANAGER" name="topMenuName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Users and Roles" name="secondMenuName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="Roles" name="thirdMenuName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="/My Company:0" name="domainName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="/My Company:0" name="currentDomainName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="/Manager:0" name="shortResourceName"/>
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="ucaplModeEnabled"/>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<div class="gensecholder clearfix">
<div class="gensecheader clearfix">
<div class="gensecbody pad10all clearfix">
<div class="gensecfooter clearfix">
<div class="gensecfootright">
<a class="genericbtn" title="New" href="javascript:doSubmit('add')">New</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pranay after viewing your code, i got javascript error. inside your html you have not defined anywhere to javascript. see the image [image]

Your html

```
<a class="genericbtn" title="New" href="javascript:doSubmit('add')">New</a>
```

Modified html

```
<a class="genericbtn" title="New" href="#">New</a>
```

Now use xpath method using javascript executor.

```
WebElement new_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'New')]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new_button);
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'New')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to locate the button directly without ancestors

```
// by class name
By.className("genericbtn")
// by title
By.cssSelector("[title='New']")
// by partial href
By.cssSelector("[href*='add']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[.="New"]
```

Just use text find `a` tag.

`.` means current context node(`a`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use either **title** or **text** property to find out the required link:

```
By.xpath("//a[@title='New']");
```

Or

```
By.linkText("New");
```

Or

```
By.xpath("//a[text()='New']");
```