# Selenium Web driver - Button is getting clicked but the next processing is not happening

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My HTML code for a NEXT button which I am trying to click is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ChildContent1$btnStep2_Submit" value="Next" onclick="waitBtn(event,&#39;df_step2&#39;);
                           OverlayProgressPanel_NoSub(&#39;ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_fsLoanData&#39;,&#39;ctl00_ctl00_upProgress&#39;);
                           " id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep2_Submit" class="btn" onmouseover="hov(this,&#39;btn btnhov&#39;);" onmouseout="hov(this,&#39;btn&#39;)" />
```

Am using the below code to click that next button:

```
        xpath = ".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep2_Submit' and @type='submit']";  // Next Button
        Function_Classes.field_click(driver,xpath);  // Click on Next button
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

But,it looks like the button is getting clicked but not going to the next page where there is one more NEXT button

I am getting below exception :

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep3_Submit' and @type='submit']"}

ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep3_Submit = this is the button on the next page and since I am not getting the next page on clicking the first NEXT button ,I would think that might be the reason..
```

Can you please help me here?

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Comment: I am very new to selenium ,so please bare with me :)

Comment: @ Jeff -- I do not think I can paste the whole link as it is against security policies

Answer (score 0):

IDs by HTML standards should be unique on the page so you shouldn't need to specify anything other than the ID in the locator. That will simplify your locators. So, in this case you can use `By.id()`.

You've added an implicit wait in the middle of your script. That leads me to believe that you don't understand how implicit waits work. An implicit wait is set once for the driver instance and lasts the life of the driver. Generally you would put this statement near the top of your script. I would advise against using implicit waits and instead prefer explicit waits (`WebDriverWait`). I've rewritten the code. I think the below should work.

```
By next2Locator = By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep2_Submit");
By next3Locator = By.id("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep3_Submit");
driver.findElement(next2Locator).click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(next3Locator)).click();
```

Suggestion: Don't overcomplicate your code by adding wrapper functions around `.click()`, etc. There's really no need for it. It makes your code harder to read and introduces unnecessary complexity. Keep it as simple as you can.

Comment: Thanks-- but it still is not working--the same issue with what I was getting with Xpath-- it clicks but still is not going to the other page (when next is clicked manually ,the processing pops up for few second and then it goes to other page ) when I am trying to run the automation code .it kind of clicks it and then gets stuck..I am not sure at all why isnt it working .. tried all --by id ,xpath even tried using actions.

Comment: Are you sure that you are clicking the right button?

Comment: Yes I am pretty much sure -- since that button is getting highlighted

Comment: do you think it can be the browser issue? The whole flow ran fine and I am just stuck since yesterday because of one button

Comment: The button gets clicked the processing pops up and it goes back to the original state --
Any idea -what the button is trying to do from the below snippet :

<input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ChildContent1$btnStep2_Submit" value="Next" onclick="waitBtn(event,'df_step2');OverlayProgressPanel_NoSub('ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_fsLoanData','ctl00_ctl00_upProgress');" id="ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_ChildContent1_btnStep2_Submit" class="btn" onmouseover="hov(this,'btn btnhov');" onmouseout="hov(this,'btn')" type="submit">

Comment: I'm not sure... you could try running it on another browser and see if it works.

Comment: that single button is working differently on different browsers -- 

I.E : single/double click manually takes you to next page

Firefox : single click is fine but double click doesnt take you to the next page and when I click again it takes me to the next page ( while I was clicking it using automation script , it was behaving as the manual double click scenario which I fixed by adding one more click step and it worked fine)

Any idea why would it happen ?

Comment: I have no idea. Double-clicking a button/link is not a typical browser/site scenario.

Comment: I would think so too,but looks like it is working fine on all the systems I have tried on -Thanks Jeff for your help !

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem inside your `html`, Because Threre are few functions are available inside your `html`, and you didn't call all functions properly. so your button click event was not fire. functions name like this `waitBtn`, `hov`.

See image for more details.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jainish ..could you please elaborate a lil biiyt more..this is working on manual click..and I had pasted a snippet of the html code

Comment: Hello @Garima, There are few possibilities are available, which cause your next button click event was not fire.
1) Check inside your js/java-script file, whether the functions name like `waitBtn`, `hov` are available or not.
2) If above mentioned functions are not available inside your java-script file, write function with same parameter as you have mentioned in your `html`.
3) If functions are already available inside your java-script file, do spell check once, function name same should be same as inside your `html` along with case sensitives. (uppercase, lowercase letter)

Comment: @Garima, Refer this answer as well, it was similar like your problem :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921453/not-able-to-click-on-button-where-xpath-is-showing-correct-as-per-selenium-ide-2/41928933#41928933

Comment: thanks Jainish.I can not go and change that html/java script,since I do not have the access ,however I fixed the automation  issue by again clicking the same button after waiting for a few seconds.It seems the button is working differently on two different browsers ,and I need to check it on the firefox.So ,it worked by adding those steps.
1) On IE - single click/double click is taking you to the next page

2) On Firefox -single click is fine but double click lets the page remain on the same page  and then I click again ,it goes to the next page

Comment: @ Jainish - Any idea why would it behave differently on different browsers though the HTML codes looks same for both

Comment: No, it would not behave differently in different browsers.